# Text Mining Large data frame with tm hangs.

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I'm running some text mining analysis with the R package tm. When i load the data to a corpus and try to run

```
searches <- tm_map(searches, stripWhitespace)
searches <- tm_map(searches, tolower)
searches <- tm_map(searches, removeWords)
```

The queries seem to be hanging on me each and takes too long to finish. I got something between 500k rows of search queries. How best can i run the tm package commands on this large data set without it eating up my memory and machine hanging on me.

FYI - I got over 8gb ram on my machine.

Comment: Have you tried it on an EC2 instance? That would help to verify if it's a performance issue rather than a data quality issue. You might also try with the plugin for distributed text mining: http://epub.wu.ac.at/3974/1/plugin.pdf